# can not remove circular dependent objects in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, cascade, circular-reference

I have two tables have circular reference to each other [image] (you can see the FK and PK i nthe image)
(In otherprotectionItems table , I have a column from Document , and that record in document is related to otherprotectionItem table ad a foreign key. the first relation is NO ACTION in delete and the second relation is CASCADE on delete)
I have this issue when I want to delete a row in otherprotectionItem table.

**Error :**

*Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.*

Answer (score 0):

Just wanto to note , I have this solution. but I prefer to have a better . Otherwise this is the answer.
I will remove the documents manually , save change in DB . and then remove the OtherprotectionItem table record

```
Data.Util.DocumentFinder.FindRecursive(item)
                        .ToList()
                        .ForEach(d => db.Entry(d).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);
                    db.SaveChanges();

 db.OtherProtectionItems.Remove(item);
                    db.SaveChanges();
```

Note : this FindRecursive is a function I create and it iterates all documents and find all documents related to this OtherprotectionItem record

Comment: You are mapping MANY-TO-MANY relation in a wrong way it should not be like this there must be a junction table

Comment: @IrshadAhmed thanks for reply. these tables are created before , and I cant make any changes now. I have to use the current structure.

Comment: Well so ... I think .AsNoTracking() will save your time instead of doing that much in code